# Getting an array from array of array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array which consists of an array objects as shown:

```
dataArr = [
    {
       id: 1,
       arrObj: [
          {
             id: 11,
             label: 'apple'
          },
          {
             id: 12,
             label: 'ball'
          }
       ]
    },
    {
       id: 2,
       arrObj: [
          {
             id: 21,
             label: 'car'
          },
          {
             id: 22,
             label: 'dog'
          }
       ]
    }
];
```

I need to extract an array consisting of only arrObj objects:

```
var newArr = [
    {
         id: 11,
         label: 'apple'
      },
      {
         id: 12,
         label: 'ball'
      },
      {
         id: 21,
         label: 'car'
      },
      {
         id: 22,
         label: 'dog'
      }
];
```

Tried using reduce method unsuccessfully:

```
 dataArr.reduce((previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, array) => {
     return previousValue. arrObj.concat(currentValue.arrObj)
 });
```

Let me know how to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close.

1. There's no `arrObj` property in your result, it's just an array.
2. You need to provide an empty array as the initial value argument to `reduce()`.

```js
const dataArr = [{
    id: 1,
    arrObj: [{
        id: 11,
        label: 'apple'
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        label: 'ball'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    arrObj: [{
        id: 21,
        label: 'car'
      },
      {
        id: 22,
        label: 'dog'
      }
    ]
  }
];

const newArr = dataArr.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
  return previousValue.concat(currentValue.arrObj)
}, []);

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: The `flatMap` solution is probably better.

Answer (score 6):

```js
let dataArr = [
    {
       id: 1,
       arrObj: [
          {
             id: 11,
             label: 'apple'
          },
          {
             id: 12,
             label: 'ball'
          }
       ]
    },
    {
       id: 2,
       arrObj: [
          {
             id: 21,
             label: 'car'
          },
          {
             id: 22,
             label: 'dog'
          }
       ]
    }
];

let result = dataArr.flatMap(e => e.arrObj)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use in one line by using [Spread Operator...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

```js
dataArr.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => [...previousValue?.arrObj, ...currentValue?.arrObj]);
```

Tip: use *Optional chaining* `?.` in case there is no property `arrObj`!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array#reduce` method as follows:

```js
let dataArr = [
    {
       id: 1,
       arrObj: [
          {
             id: 11,
             label: 'apple'
          },
          {
             id: 12,
             label: 'ball'
          }
       ]
    },
    {
       id: 2,
       arrObj: [
          {
             id: 21,
             label: 'car'
          },
          {
             id: 22,
             label: 'dog'
          }
       ]
    }
];

let newArr = dataArr.reduce((acc,cur) => [...acc, ...cur.arrObj], []);

console.log( newArr );
```